# Magento2.3.1: Transactional emails are not going to the customer

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.1

The transactional emails are not coming to the customer when the user placed an order from my website.

**Website is** : https://www.depoto.com/.

1. I have checked the SMTP configuration and it's fine.
2. I tried to send test email from the server. Its working fine and recipient received the email with test details. I am using **GODADDY**
3. CRON is also working fine. I checked by using this command: `php bin/magento cron:run`
4. I have already checked with the DNS for emails also. Everything is configured properly.
5. I checked in `var/system.log` and `exception.log` also. Didn't find any issues.

Comment: Please enable cod mathod and check email is working or not. If it's working properly than it's issue from payment method.

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara, It sems error in email template. Please add new email template with only simple text and configure to email orders and test. Also make sure error log are enabled. so you can see what is error from log.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to check the below point:

1. Go to **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Advanced** -> **System**
2. Under Mail Sending Settings make sure -  **Disable Email Communications** is set to **No**.
3. Also verify your Host and Port fields if you are using any external mailing server.
4. Go to **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Sales** -> **Sales Emails**
5. Under General Settings tab, choose **Asynchronous sending** to **Disable**
6. Under **Order** tab Enabled to **Yes**
7. Now clear/refresh your cache.

Comment: The issue may be related to the payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your email templates. Are you created any `custom template` or changes in `existing template` ? Sometimes there is error in email template so for that email are not send. In past I face this type of issue. I created one custom template but i never use it. After creation of custom template, emails are not going through. I spent 2 days to find this solution. Than after i just **removed custom email template** file from my folder and emails sending are started.

Try to remove your custom email template or changes in existing email template and test it.

Do one thing also. Check your logs. You can find error.